# How to query implicit properties of owl:equivalentclass

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I want to query an ontology which contains implicit properties hold by `owl:equivalentclass` objects. How can I achieve this?

The ontology holds triples like this:

`<plantURI> rdf:type <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FLOPO_0004148>`.

The class `<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FLOPO_0004148>` has the following definition:

```
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FLOPO_0004148">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000051"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom>
                    <owl:Class>
                        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PO_0009046"/>
                            <owl:Restriction>
                                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0000053"/>
                                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000320"/>
                            </owl:Restriction>
                        </owl:intersectionOf>
                    </owl:Class>
                </owl:someValuesFrom>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">flower green</rdfs:label>
    </owl:Class>
```

However, I don't want to query simply for the URI like this:

`SELECT * {
?s rdf:type <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FLOPO_0004148>
}`

but I want to query sometimes only for one of its implicit properties, for example the property `<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000320>` ("green") - searching for all plants that are green in any way.

So, the best query would look like this:

```
SELECT * {
?s ?p <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000320>
}
```

Which gives me the  object, because implicitly the object  holds this property.

This probably involves reasoning in Virtuoso. However, after some hours I cannot come up with any solution how to do this in SPARQL.

Comment: short answer: not possible with Virtuoso Open Source 7.x as it needs the OWL RL reasoning profile which afaik isn't available in that version. Maybe in Virtuoso 8 - I don't know - but there is no open source version for Virtuoso 8

Comment: I would suggest raising this to the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com). I believe @AKSW is correct, that you will need the advanced reasoning features of Virtuoso 8, which remains commercial-only (i.e., no Open Source Edition) -- but perhaps more detail of what you're doing would reveal another option.

Comment: I feared so! Thank you both for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Virtuoso provides reasoning and inference in two forms.
1. Built-in -- this is based on canned rules covering the relations semantics for owl:equivalentClass, owl:equivalentProperty, owl:inverseOf, owl:sameAs, owl:InverseFunctionalProperty, owl:SymmetricProperty, rdfs:subClassOf, rdfs:subPropertyOf (this is supported in both open source and commercial editions)

2. Custom -- this is based on custom rules crafted using SPARQL and the Rules Language, courtesy of terms from the SPIN Ontology (this is a commercial edition only feature).

You appear right now to simply require owl:equivalentClass reasoning, so you can look at the following built-in inference and reasoning examples:

Equivalent Class Reasoning Enabled

```
DEFINE input:inference 'urn:owl:equivalent:class:inference:rules'

PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bmo: <http://purl.org/bmo/ns#> 
PREFIX fibo: <https://spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/ontology/FND/AgentsAndPeople/People/Person>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>


SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
        ?s a fibo:person .

      }
LIMIT 20
```

[Live Query Results Page](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=DEFINE%20input%3Ainference%20%27urn%3Aowl%3Aequivalent%3Aclass%3Ainference%3Arules%27%0D%0A%0D%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20bmo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fbmo%2Fns%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20fibo%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fspec.edmcouncil.org%2Ffibo%2Fontology%2FFND%2FAgentsAndPeople%2FPeople%2FPerson%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Fs%20a%20fibo%3Aperson%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2020&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) (solution is produced based on effects of reasoning and inference)

Equivalent Class Reasoning Disabled (notice DEFINE input:inference pragma commented out)

```
# DEFINE input:inference 'urn:owl:equivalent:class:inference:rules'

PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bmo: <http://purl.org/bmo/ns#> 
PREFIX fibo: <https://spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/ontology/FND/AgentsAndPeople/People/Person>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>


SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
        ?s a fibo:person .

      }
LIMIT 20
```

[Live Query Results Page](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=%23%20DEFINE%20input%3Ainference%20%27urn%3Aowl%3Aequivalent%3Aclass%3Ainference%3Arules%27%0D%0A%0D%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20bmo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fbmo%2Fns%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20fibo%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fspec.edmcouncil.org%2Ffibo%2Fontology%2FFND%2FAgentsAndPeople%2FPeople%2FPerson%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Fs%20a%20fibo%3Aperson%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alimit%2020&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) (should be empty)

[Example source code document](https://github.com/OpenLinkSoftware/SPASQL-Utility-Showcase-Queries/blob/master/equivalent-class-reasoning-uriburner.sql) from our [Github Repository](https://github.com/OpenLinkSoftware/).